# Type mismatch. Required: Flow<ResponseState<T>> Found: Flow<ResponseState<List<CoinIcon>>>

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I have ResponseState.kt class for checking response state as below

```
    sealed class ResponseState<out T> {

    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : ResponseState<T>()

    data class Error(val message: String) : ResponseState<Nothing>()

    object Loading: ResponseState<Nothing>()

}
```

and this is my repository class

```
    class CoinRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: CoinRemoteDataSource
) : CoinRepository {

    override fun <T> getCoinIcon(): Flow<ResponseState<T>> =
        flow {
            emit(ResponseState.Loading)
            emit(ResponseState.Success(remoteDataSource.getCoinIcons()))
        }.catch { error ->
            emit(ResponseState.Error(error.localizedMessage))
        }
}
```

remoteDataSource.getCoinIcons - returns -> `List<CoinIcon>`

I got this compile error -> `Type mismatch. Required: Flow<ResponseState<T>> Found: Flow<ResponseState<List<CoinIcon>>>`

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

`getCoinIcon()` is declared as a generic method with a type parameter `T`, and `T` defines the return type. This is incorrect because type parameters of a generic method are defined by the *caller* of the method, but in your case the body of the method is supposed to define it.

The method should instead have a fixed return type, not generic:

```kotlin
class CoinRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: CoinRemoteDataSource
) : CoinRepository {

    override fun getCoinIcon(): Flow<ResponseState<List<Coin>>> =
        flow {
            emit(ResponseState.Loading)
            emit(ResponseState.Success(remoteDataSource.getCoinIcons()))
        }.catch { error ->
            emit(ResponseState.Error(error.localizedMessage))
        }
}
```

Comment: But there is a problem, when I collect responses on the view model, ResponseState.Success data return ANY type but it should be List<CoinIcon>                     
         ------------ viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getCoinIcon().collect {
                when(it) {
                    is ResponseState.Success<*> -> {
                        it.data
                    }
                }
            }
        }-------------------- What should I do when I have to collect and need to data as List<CoinIcon> ?

Comment: Ah I see, so then yes, you can use a generic `ResponseState<T>` for this. I edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a compilation error of the IDE. After re-reading your question, I checked my project again and... As you said, I compile error code like you.

But I managed to fix it. Try clean project then sync gradle again.

And... Opp... Everything is back to normal. So I think this error is because the IDE is having some conflict with the Kotlin library.

I am using Kotlin 1.5.21, Android Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 and gradle is 7.0.1.

**Edit:**

And at function `getCoinIcon()` you should return about `Flow<ResponseState<List<CoinIcon>>>` like below:

```
class CoinRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: CoinRemoteDataSource
): CoinRepository {

    override fun getCoinIcon(): Flow<ResponseState<List<CoinIcon>>> = flow {
        emit(ResponseState.Loading)
        emit(ResponseState.Success(remoteDataSource.getCoinIcons()))
    }.catch { error ->
        emit(ResponseState.Error(error.localizedMessage))
    }
}
```

Comment: @FurkanPaşaoğlu I have updated my answer already.

Comment: Yeah. I hope you accept my answer. Thank you so much!